# IE: cursor jump to start in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

In a text input, if text exists, and you click to add more the cursor automatically jumps to the start. It seems to only happen in IE.

I've been googling this for a while now and tried loads of examples that I found but nothing seems to be working. Unfortunately, the input is written in a jsp which I don't have control over and I think the only reason I have this problem is because there is some javascript hard coded in there.

```
<input type="text" id="simpleSearchString" class="text" onfocus="javascript:this.value=this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')" onblur="javascript:this.value=this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')" value="" maxlength="255" name="searchCriteria.simpleSearchString">
```

All I want to do really is remove this jump.

I thought adding the following code would have helped but didn't seem to do anything:

```
jQuery("input#simpleSearchString").focus();
```

I'm not 100% sure what dev are trying to achieve with the 'javascript:this...etc' but maybe I could find a way of removing it.

Comment: The regexes are stripping leading/trailing whitespace from the field. Most likely this is causing the cursor to jump, as IE assumes the content's changed and invalidates the old cursor position.

Comment: What about removing the `onfocus` and `onblur` from the input element? this could easily be done with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, i just found out that this javascript was put in place as any leading/trailing whitespace was affecting the results of a search. From the jsp i can see it uses something called <bee:trimmed...

Comment: Hi Dan D, was thinking the exact same but just found out this code needs to be in there. (see comment above)

Comment: Hello did you ever find the source of this problem? I am struggling with the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could kill those inline events and plug in your own;

```
var el = $("#simpleSearchString");
el[0].onfocus = el[0].onblur = null;

$(el).on("focus blur", function(e) {
    this.value = $.trim(this.value);    
    if ((e.type === "focus") && this.createTextRange) {
        var r = this.createTextRange();
        r.moveStart("character", this.value.length);
        r.select();
    }
});
```

(This assumes its only IE that requires you to reposition the caret)

Comment: worked a treat! thank you so much. you've no idea how annoying that's been.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and used this solution; it saves the cursor from jumping on the initial focus, but if the user clicks within the input it will still jump to the start. Do you have a fix for that by chance?

Comment: This solved the issue where IE would change the curser position to index 0 after typing something then clicking the textbox again.